# Can't receive CONNACK by using MQTT protocol to connect to IBM Iot foundation

Tags: mqtt

I have used my device to connect to IBM Iot Foundation, as I know, there are two ways to establish the connection: quickstart and the registered device. firstly, I tried to connect to the quickstart. (quickstart.messaging.internetofthings.ibmcloud.com)  I downloaded the C/C++ MQTT Embedded client library from paho.(http://www.eclipse.org/paho/) the socket has successfully established and there is no wrong in the code, buf after I established the mqttconnect, I can't receive the response CONNACK and it directly goto exit. what may cause this problem?

```
len = MQTTSerialize_connect((unsigned char*)buf, buflen, &data);
rc=transport_sendPacketBuffer(mysock,buf,len);
/****wait for connack***/
if (MQTTPacket_read(buf, buflen, transport_getdata) == CONNACK)
{
    unsigned char sessionPresent, connack_rc;
    printf("receive connack\n");// can't print this setence.
    if (MQTTDeserialize_connack(&sessionPresent, &connack_rc, buf, buflen) != 1 || connack_rc != 0)
    {
        printf("Unable to connect, return code %d\n", connack_rc);
        goto exit;
    }
}
else
    goto exit;  

topicString.cstring = "iot-2/evt/status/fmt/json";
len += MQTTSerialize_publish((unsigned char *)(buf + len), buflen - len, 0, 0, 0, 0, topicString, (unsigned char *)payload, payloadlen);  
    len += MQTTSerialize_disconnect((unsigned char *)(buf + len), buflen - len);
rc=transport_sendPacketBuffer(mysock,buf,len);

if (rc == len)
    printf("Successfully published\n");
else
    printf("Publish failed\n");
exit:
   printf("close socket.\n");
   transport_close(mysock);
```

Comment: I tried the simplest sample qos0pub.c which was in the folder MQTTPacket. In this sample, it connects,published and disconnect all in one go (the QOS is set to be 0) so after I request to connect to the server ,if successfully connected it should response connack to me,but I just can't receive it. I will add the core of the program in my question.

Comment: Presumably the content of your connection request in variable buf referred to in lines 1/2 of your snippet above is wrong in some way - what is in it?

Comment: I have already resolved the problem, It just because my compiler didn't transfer the byte in big-endian,so the byte is reversed.well, thank you all the same!